# Modify query so it gets the requested values

Tags: php, mysql

Please I have this query here which I use in order to extract some rows from the database.

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT u.*, SUM(c.ts) AS total_sum1, SUM(m.bv) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id ,SUM(points) AS ts FROM coupon GROUP BY user_id) c 
 ON   u.user_id like'%$search%'
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id ,SUM(points) AS bv FROM matching GROUP BY user_id) m 
ON u.user_id=m.user_id 

GROUP BY u.user_id limit $offset,$rows");
```

I need to modify it so it only queries the rows that satisfy this condition:

```
u.user_id like '%$search%'
```

Where should I put the above condition?
I tried adding an AND operator but it still wouldn't give one row, since user_id's are different from each other.

Thanks

Comment: Um, WHERE userid LIKE '%$search%' ? Note that this cannot use an index

Comment: Maybe you could tell what do you actually try to query. Adding `WHERE u.user_id LIKE '%$search%'` before the last `GROUP BY` seems to be the thing to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `WHERE` clause in order to add that condition:

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT u.*, SUM(c.ts) AS total_sum1, SUM(m.bv) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id ,SUM(points) AS ts FROM coupon GROUP BY user_id) c 
 ON   u.user_id like'%$search%'
LEFT JOIN 
 (SELECT user_id ,SUM(points) AS bv FROM matching GROUP BY user_id) m 
ON u.user_id=m.user_id 
WHERE u.user_id like '%$search%'
GROUP BY u.user_id limit $offset,$rows");
```

Side notes:

- The `mysql_*` library is deprecated, consider upgrading to a modern API such as [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) or MySQLi
- The use of Prepared Statements with bound parameters is preferred to concatenating variables into SQL. Prepared Statements are much more secure and easier to use because you don't have to worry about escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this SQL.(I don't know PHP)

```
SELECT 
       u.*, 
       SUM(c.points) AS total_sum1, 
       SUM(m.points) AS total_sum 
FROM users u 

INNER JOIN coupon c  ON   u.user_id=m.user_id 
INNER JOIN matching  m  ON u.user_id=m.user_id 

WHERE u.user_id like '%$search%'
GROUP BY u.user_id limit $offset,$rows" ;
```